How to create private offer with absolute pricing in Azure partner center using APIs available
By following official documentation, I was able to create private offer with discounted pricing, however the steps for creation of private offer seemed unclear.
link to doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace/create-direct-isv-to-customer-private-offer-api#sample-request-body-using-absolute-pricing-to-customize-pricing-for-existing-public-plan-only

Here I am unable to understand what exactly needed to be called and what to pass in request body, I am unable to find  price-and-availability-private-offer-plan since it isn't in my resource tree
I've tried to modify the payload for discount pricing but schema validation was failed, Did R&D on "private offer resource" creation but there was no schema available for the same.
